# localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 2984

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04

I set up and configured a multi-node Hadoop .Will appear when I start
My Ubuntu is 16.04 and Hadoop is 3.0.2

```
Starting namenodes on [master]
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 2984
Starting secondary namenodes [master]
master: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 3175
2018-07-17 02:19:39,470 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

Who can tell me which link is wrong?

Comment: We need to know more about your configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the word "`native`" to your HADOOP_OPTS like this:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

Comment: Is in hadoop-env.sh? or in ~/.bashrc?

Comment: In .bashrc file

Comment: I add this but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fixed it by ensuring that the datanode and namenode locations have the right permissions and are owned by the user starting hadoop daemons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and tried the above method, but it doesn't work.

I set `XXX_USER` in all xxx-env.sh files, and got the same result.

Finally I set `HADOOP_SHELL_EXECNAME="root"` in `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hdfs`, and the error disappeared.

The default value of `HADOOP_SHELL_EXECNAME` is "`HDFS`".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I renamed my Ubuntu home directory, and had to edit `core-site.xml`, changing the value of the property `hadoop.tmp.dir` to the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Check that

1. The directory path properties in hdfs-site.xml under $HADOOP_CONF_DIR are pointing to valid locations.
   `dfs.namenode.name.dir`
   `dfs.datanode.data.dir`
   `dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir`
2. Hadoop user must have write permission for these paths

If the write permission is not present for the mentioned paths, then the processes might not start and the error you see can occur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you just need to check `hadoop/logs` directory and look for a .log file for datanode, type more nameofthefile.log and check for the errors, mine was a problem in to configuration, I fixed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in thew wrong setting of "dfs.namenode.name.dir" in hdfs-site.xml.
You should keep it right,change as fallows:
`vim hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.data.dir</name>
   <value>${HADOOP_HOME}/data</value>
</property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.data.dir}/data</value>
  </property>
```